# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in

Tags: php

I need help.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\addcomment.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\read.php(48): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\addcomment.php on line 15

read.php line 45-52

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
if ($_SESSION['user']) {
include 'addcomment.php'; }
else {
echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" style="width:330px;" role="alert">Error</div>' ; }
?>
```

addcomment.php line 14-15

```
$yorum = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO yorumlar SET yorum_gonderen=?, yorum_icerik=?, yorum_konu_id=?");
    $ekle = $yorum->execute(array("$kullanici","$yorum","$id"));
```

Comment: You have `$yorum = $db->prepare(` and then `array("$kullanici","$yorum","$id")`, so you need to change 1 of the variable names `$yorum`

Comment: thank you so much my friend. How could I not see it? :D